# When does the triangle inequality apply for norms?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) wikipedia page for the triangle inequality, it states the triangle inequality for norms:

$||x+y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$

but on [this](https://leducjustin.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/chapter-2-introduction-to-vector-spaces2.pdf) example about the French Railway Metric I found (page 19), it uses an equality instead. Why is this the case?

Comment: If $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$ then certainly it follows that $\|x+y\|\leq \|x\|+\|y\|$.  Remember that $\leq$ is interpreted as less than *or* equal.  In order for it to be a norm in the first place it must have the triangle inequality.  Certainly, some norms can be more interesting and be more restrictive, but it still satisfies the weaker requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example given in those notes on page 19-20 does not use the triangle inequality at all, except for saying that the user can verify that the metric function satisfies the properties needed for a distance function (one of which is the triangle inequality). So it does not "use an equallity instead."